# Loop two files in parallel with awk, print matched and unmatched

Tags: awk

I have got two files and would like to read them into my command in parallel line by line. The command works on it own:

The first argument is matched in the first column, then it has to match two number comparisons in column 4 and 5 in order to print column 9 from the data.file. This one here actually works:

```
awk '$1=="argument1" && $4<"argument2" && $5>"argument3" {print f} {f=$9}' ../data.file >> OUTPUT.txt
```

**1)** I would like to run this now with the arguments replaced as variables and with the input from two different files. 
Something like this:

```
cat FILE1a FILE2a | while read FILE1 && read FILE2; do
awk -v j="$FILE1" -v i="$FILE2" '$1==j && $4<i && $5>i {print f} {f=$9}' ../data.file >> OUTPUT.txt
done
```

But I dont get any output from it for some reason. I have tried writing the variables with " and ', but I cant get an output here. Could you please let me know how to fix this? Very much appreciated.

**2)** I also wanted to print "no_match_found" if the arguments are not match with something like that:

```
awk '$1=="argument1" && $4<"argument2" && $5>"argument3" {print f} {f=$9} END { if (!p) print "No_match_found"}' ../data.file >> OUTPUT.txt
```

This seems to work with the command but prints "No_match_found" not only when no match is found, but also when it is actually found. I am a bit confused.

So the whole command should look like this, but I just cant get it to work:

```
cat FILE1a FILE2a | while read FILE1 && read FILE2; do
awk -v j="$FILE1" -v i="$FILE2" '$1==j && $4<i && $5>i {print f} {f=$9} END { if (!p) print "No_match_found"}' ../data.file >> OUTPUT.txt
done
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here are the examples of the files:
**FILE1**

```
scaffold100
scaffold100
scaffold100
scaffold110
scaffold127
```

**FILE2**

```
20331
63580
82754
80477
114357
```

**data.file**

```
scaffold100 RGF GHT 267634  268411  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.13_LINE-1_reverse_transcriptase-like
scaffold100 RGF GHT 269975  271003  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.14_LINE-1_reverse_transcriptase-like
scaffold100 RGF GHT 272492  272848  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.15_Pleckstrin-likey_domain-containing_protein_1
scaffold100 RGF GHT 276355  277065  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.16_NA
scaffold100 RGF GHT 278580  281340  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.17_putative_RNA_pseudouridine_synthase_YlyB
scaffold100 RGF GHT 296344  308565  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.18_Outer_membrane_protein_assembly_factor_BamB
scaffold100 RGF GHT 324074  337460  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.19_hypothetical_protein_AK812_SmicGene20166
scaffold100 RGF GHT 344155  379840  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.20_Procollagen_galactosyltransferase_1
scaffold100 RGF GHT 392748  402819  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.21_Alkylated_DNA_repair_protein_alkB-like_8
scaffold100 RGF GHT 404481  415086  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.22_Voltage-dependent_P/Q-type_calcium_channel_subunit_alpha-1A
scaffold100 RGF GHT 461507  466605  .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.23_hypothetical_protein_AK812_SmicGene32864
scaffold100 RGF GHT 20321   21040   .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.3_Gamma-tubulin_complex_component_4-like
scaffold100 RGF GHT 53560   69701   .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.4_COBW_domain-containing_protein_1
scaffold100 RGF GHT 72734   97123   .   -   .   ID=scaffold100.5_Polycystin-2
scaffold127 RGF GHT 106337  122095  .   -   .   ID=scaffold127.6_Histone-lysine_N-methyltransferase_SMYD3
scaffold127 RGF GHT 155484  177458  .   +   .   ID=scaffold127.9_Tetratricopeptide_repeat
```

Desired output:

```
ID=scaffold100.3_Gamma-tubulin_complex_component_4-like
ID=scaffold100.4_COBW_domain-containing_protein_1
ID=scaffold100.5_Polycystin-2
No_match_found
ID=scaffold127.6_Histone-lysine_N-methyltransferase_SMYD3
```

Comment: Provide your whole script. Your requirements are quite unclear now. Rather than explaining your attempt, post your problem with an "exact" input and output expected.

Comment: Also where does your `while` read loops read from? there is no stuff to read from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    ++cnt[$1]
    beg[$1,cnt[$1]] = $4
    end[$1,cnt[$1]] = $5
    map[$1,$4,$5] = $9
    next
}
{
    result = "No_match_found"
    for (i=1; i<=cnt[$1]; i++) {
        if ( (beg[$1,i] < $2) && ($2 < end[$1,i]) ) {
            result = map[$1,beg[$1,i],end[$1,i]]
            break
        }
    }
    print result
}
```

.

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -f tst.awk data.file -
ID=scaffold100.3_Gamma-tubulin_complex_component_4-like
ID=scaffold100.4_COBW_domain-containing_protein_1
ID=scaffold100.5_Polycystin-2
No_match_found
ID=scaffold127.6_Histone-lysine_N-methyltransferase_SMYD3
```